# Ruby Gem .gem is empty after 'gem build'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I used Swagger CodeGen to generate a Ruby client for an API.  Here is what the resulting .gemspec file looks like:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#
=begin
#convertapi

#Convert API lets you effortlessly convert file formats and types.

OpenAPI spec version: v1

Generated by: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
Swagger Codegen version: unset

=end

$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "cloudmersiveConvertApiClient/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "cloudmersiveConvertApiClient"
  s.version     = CloudmersiveConvertApiClient::VERSION
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.authors     = ["Cloudmersive"]
  s.email       = [""]
  s.homepage    = "https://www.cloudmersive.com/convert-api"
  s.summary     = "Convert API lets you effortlessly convert file formats and types."
  s.description = "Convert files and content between file formats. Convert data between file formats. Instantly."
  s.license     = "Apache 2.0"
  s.required_ruby_version = ">= 1.9"

  s.add_runtime_dependency 'typhoeus', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'json', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.0'

  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec', '~> 3.6', '>= 3.6.0'
  s.add_development_dependency 'vcr', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
  s.add_development_dependency 'webmock', '~> 1.24', '>= 1.24.3'
  s.add_development_dependency 'autotest', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.6'
  s.add_development_dependency 'autotest-rails-pure', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.2'
  s.add_development_dependency 'autotest-growl', '~> 0.2', '>= 0.2.16'
  s.add_development_dependency 'autotest-fsevent', '~> 0.2', '>= 0.2.12'

  s.files         = `find *`.split("\n").uniq.sort.select{|f| !f.empty? }
  s.test_files    = `find spec/*`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = []
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

Here is what the directory structure looks like:

[image: Dir structure]

However, when I build it, it produces a very small .gem file.  If I then install that gem and I go look in the folder where it was installed, the folder is completed empty - nothing is inside.

Any ideas why this would happen?  New to Ruby so any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows operating system the following two lines would not obviously work:

```
s.files         = `find *`.split("\n").uniq.sort.select{|f| !f.empty? }
s.test_files    = `find spec/*`.split("\n")
```

They are used to produce arrays of files (sources and tests) out of your current directory structure. Both call a system to execute `find` command which does unlikely happen to exist in Windows. To overcome the issue (since your `gem` is relatively small) just list all the files manually, or use [`Dir#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) or use any unix to build the `gem`. Something like that should work (not tested):

```
s.files = Dir['./**/*'] # .select { |f| ... } # condition to include file
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I was building and installing a gem locally on Windows. I used MINGW32 console (Git Bash) to build the gem and it worked as you suggested.
Didn't change the gemspec file at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an add-on the accepted answer, the typical approach is having your file list synced with the committed `git` files. This is how Bundler would generate the relevant part of the spec file:

```
  spec.files = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  end
```

This is obviously convenient as it can easily be controlled via `.gitignore`, etc. If not using `git` or if you don't have it installed for some strange reason, disregard this.